# How the rollups know that a given message in the inbox is for them and not for another rollup

Tags: smart-rollup, rollup, scoru

One thing that is not clear to me is how the rollups know that a given message in the inbox is for them and not for another rollup. It seems that the messages have no target address?

[Source of discussion Twitter](https://twitter.com/jagracar/status/1642173860551294976)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed, the external messages of the inbox have to be parsed by the rollup for the rollup logic to decide to process it or not. No format is enforced by the shared inbox to keep this communication channel as flexible as possible for rollup devs.

Comment: Q: And are you working in some kind of rollup message standard? Otherwise it sounds to me like chaos. A message might be process by different rollups and the sender might not have control over that?

Comment: A: A standard could emerge from the ecosystem to make parsing these "packets" more efficient and robust. However, notice that not having too much structure and control at this level of the system permits a large set of "data link"-level mechanisms: broadcast, replication, etc.
By the way, "internal messages" can be an easy way to have more structure in your rollup inputs. Internal messages are produced by L1 smart contracts and target a specific rollup: using such a smart contract as a post officer could make you work around the "chaos". :-)

Comment: Q: These are also sent to the global rollup inbox, right? Do you have an example of how they look like? I understand it has the parameter values of the rollup entrypoint. How is the rollup address written in the message?

Comment: A: That's a mere transfer to the rollup address, similar to a smart contract call.